# how to protect from Network scanner on android?

Tags: ids, android, physical, network-scanners, intrusion

How can I block and detect network scanners on android platforms to stop scanning vlan of my hot spot.

My question is:

- which scanners they use?
- how can i detect such scanners?
- Can i protect LAN by MIKROTIK or there are better tools available.

Comment: Are you asking about how to protect your android devices from network sanners, or how to protect your network from network scanners running on android devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of attack are very moving in form, tools, and manners. (one day it's `vlan`, that offer some backdoors, another day, there is `SIP`... or some `.mp3` plugins...)

Depending on what's new security failure where discovered...

But Android community is very quick to build patchs and correction for dangerous sercurity failures.

So the right answer is (as I think):

- Any scanner, depending on which failure have to be exploited
- Don't try to do that if you're not a network security expert;-)
- Keep your system up to date!

And if you're in doubt, ask a friend to trace network activities and maybe to inspect your system.

(Don't buy expensive `anti-virus` or other `anti-spy` software, as they are as obscure as malwares you try to stay away.)